# Fortran-C interoperativity basic example

Tags: c, fortran, mixing

I'm trying to learn how to call a Fortran function or subroutine from a C program and I made this simple example:

The Fortran function area.f90 is

```
function Area_Circle(r)

implicit none

real(kind(1.d0)) , intent(out):: Area_Circle
real(kind(1.d0)), intent(in) :: r

real(kind(1.d0)), parameter :: Pi = acos(-1.d0)

Area_Circle = Pi * r * r

end function Area_Circle
```

and the C main.c program

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern double Area_Circle_(double *r);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    double r;

    printf("Enter the radius\n");
    scanf("%lf", &r);

    printf("The area is %lf\n", Area_Circle_(&r));

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to compile and build with the command

```
gcc -o app main.c area.f90 -lgfortran
```

and the exit is

```
area.f90:1:0:

 function Area_Circle(r)
 
Error: Symbol at (1) is not a DUMMY variable
```

What should I do to compile and run correctly this?

P.D.: I don't usually work in Fortran but some of my colleagues yes. For this reason I want to learn Fortran-C interoperativity.

Comment: Take a look here at very simple sample showing how to go all the way from Python to Fortran via C. You also have a sample based on `f90wrap`: https://github.com/mkopsnc/marmot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things that need to be addressed.

Your Fortran function `Area_Circle` is incorrect: The function name's type aka its return type cannot have an `intent`.

There is a module defined in the Fortran standard which makes interoperability of Fortran-C well-defined and portable: `iso_c_binding`. You should make use of it, e.g. note the `bind(c)` attribute and the real kind `c_double`.

Fortran is case-insensitive s.t. you need to call it in all lowercase in your C program, i.e. `area_circle` instead of `Area_Circle_`.
This behavior can be overridden by using `bind(c, name="<some_name>")`.

---

The Fortran file `area.f90`

```
function Area_Circle(r) bind(c)
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
  implicit none

  real(c_double), intent(in) :: r
  real(c_double)             :: Area_Circle

  real(c_double), parameter :: PI = acos(-1.d0)

  Area_Circle = PI * r * r
end function
```

The C file `main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern double area_circle(double *r);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    double r;

    printf("Enter the radius\n");
    scanf("%lf", &r);

    printf("The area is %lf\n", area_circle(&r));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @francescalus I appended a remark about the optional `name` argument of the `bind` attribute.